# Passing a bind variable to view accessor conditionally

Tags: groovy, oracle-adf

I am new to Adf and i have got a requirement. I have a VO(VO1) which has a View Accessor(PVA) for linking another VO(VO2).

This VO2 is related to flex fields(I am not completely aware of it). But it has something to do with code_combinations table.

Now this view accessor is having a bind variable called 'Bind_ExtraWhereClause' which is of type 'String' and has the following groovy expression in it:
`"\${COMBINATION_TABLE}.ACCOUNT_TYPE = 'L' AND \${COMBINATION_TABLE}.SUMMARY_FLAG != 'Y' AND \${COMBINATION_TABLE}.DETAIL_POSTING_ALLOWED_FLAG = 'Y' AND \${COMBINATION_TABLE}.ENABLED_FLAG = 'Y'"`

This expression is used for validation purpose.

I don't know exact point during runtime when this view accessor is getting executed. Now i need to change the above bind variable groovy expression to this  `"\${COMBINATION_TABLE}.SUMMARY_FLAG != 'Y' AND \${COMBINATION_TABLE}.DETAIL_POSTING_ALLOWED_FLAG = 'Y' AND \${COMBINATION_TABLE}.ENABLED_FLAG = 'Y'"` based on a condition in my code.

How can i achieve that?

I have already tried to implement the following two methods:

1) created a transient attribute in VO1 called checkflag of type string and setting this checkflag in my code to either of following values "YES" or "NO". then i edited the bind variable groovy expression like this:

```
checkflag!="YES"?return "\${COMBINATION_TABLE}.ACCOUNT_TYPE = 'L' AND \${COMBINATION_TABLE}.SUMMARY_FLAG != 'Y' AND \${COMBINATION_TABLE}.DETAIL_POSTING_ALLOWED_FLAG = 'Y' AND \${COMBINATION_TABLE}.ENABLED_FLAG = 'Y'":return "\${COMBINATION_TABLE}.SUMMARY_FLAG != 'Y' AND \${COMBINATION_TABLE}.DETAIL_POSTING_ALLOWED_FLAG = 'Y' AND \${COMBINATION_TABLE}.ENABLED_FLAG = 'Y'"
```

so when checkflag is "NO", it takes first condition and when its "YES", it takes the second condition.

2)I cleared the Bind_ExtraWhereClause value from the VA and tried to populate it from VOROWIMPL in the getPVA() method as follows:

```
public RowSet getPVA(){
RowSet rs = (RowSet)getAttributeInternal(PVA);
if("NO".equals(checkflag)){   rs.setNameWhereClauseParam("Bind_ExtraWhereClause","\${COMBINATION_TABLE}.ACCOUT_TYPE = 'L' AND \${COMBINATION_TABLE}.SUMMARY_FLAG != 'Y' AND \${COMBINATION_TABLE}.DETAIL_POSTING_ALLOWED_FLAG = 'Y' AND \${COMBINATION_TABLE}.ENABLED_FLAG = 'Y'");}
else{rs.setNameWhereClauseParam("Bind_ExtraWhereClause","\${COMBINATION_TABLE}.SUMMARY_FLAG != 'Y' AND \${COMBINATION_TABLE}.DETAIL_POSTING_ALLOWED_FLAG = 'Y' AND \${COMBINATION_TABLE}.ENABLED_FLAG = 'Y'");}
rs.executeQuery();
return rs;
}
```

Unfortunately, both the approaches didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand 100% what are you trying to achieve, but it looks like you need a dynamic view link condition.

Instead of trying to change the view link expression, use instead a transient field in VO1, but this time use an SQL Expression as Default Value.

You need to start thinking about it differently: instead of making your view link dynamic, move the dynamic logic on Query level - by using SQL Calculated attributes.